# Active application NOT installed in disk C after re-install Window

Tags: window

I've just re-installed my Window 10. In my previous window, I had installed all software in Disk D, not in Disk C, therefore, they are still there now (I just re-install only my window). My question is how to re-active that applications.
(sorry for my bad English, and thank in advance)

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstalled Windows you probably formatted C partition. When previous installation of your OS was on C drive you are lost your registry and some other config files which are required to run your apps from D drive (but still some simple apps can work properly). If your OS has been installed on D you can try to find a tool for import registry, settings and maybe some other required files (like assemblies from GAC), but I believe clean installation of the applications is the best way to resurrect them.